# When Querying with Boolean Filters in GraphQL, how do I cover the case of "No Filter"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, graphql-js, react-query

I have the following hook / query in my frontend, which fetches an some articles and has a filter so it can fetch only the articles that have been proofread or all the articles that have not been:

```
export default function useArticles(isProofread) {
  return useQuery("articles", async () => {
    const { articles } = await request(
      endpoint,
      gql`
        query {
          articles(isProofread: ${isProofread}) {
            id
            title
          }
        }
      `
    )
    return articles
  })
}
```

I do not understand how to fetch *all* articles though? I am always passing `isProofread` which will either be `true` or `false`. But I struggle to understand how I would just not pass this into my query at all? I have tried not passing the variable into the function, but then `undefined` will still be passed into the query template, giving me an error.

How can I make this work?

Comment: use variables, not string literals!!! https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have fixed this now! My problem still remains though, I don't know how to *not* pass this down and thus get all my articles. Do you have an idea how I could include that option?

Comment: ask API devs ... IMHO this condition should be a part of `where` arg  ... as bool [if exists] can be only true or false ... in the meantime use 2 different requests/queries (if undefined without arg and existing one for true/false)

Comment: Does it work if you pass `null`? This does entirely depend on the API schema itself, so no-one here can answer this for you without that.

Comment: @loganfsmyth thanks a lot. but isn't there a general recommendation on how to handle these cases? I have the same problem in the backend, basically. I just don't know how to handle these cases - I do not want to use strings or anything non-boolean, but I don't know how I could cover this. I could have a second variable that just checks whether the filter is set, but this also seems cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

> I have the same problem in the backend...

It looks like you're responsible for API, too.

Your API should:

- use meaningful names:

  - an `isProofread` should be a prop [of entry];
- **definitely handle** `undefined` - **lack of value is a value/state, too**:

  - e.g. `if (undefined != args.proofread) filters['proofread'] = args.proofread;`
- support `where` variable/arg/condition:

  - `where:{ proofread: { eq: false } }`;
  - `where:{ proofread: { in: [false, true] } }` - equal to `undefined`;